# how to start arduino in windows with cl compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arduino, cl

I've just bought a toolkit for arduino and until I get the package, I would like to start discovering the libraries. It seems arduino depends on its own IDE. Inside the folder of arduino, there is a `main.cpp`, therefore I would like to compile this file using `cl` compiler visual studio 2013. Unfortunately there is no `readme` file. I don't know which libraries should I add and use. In `main.cpp`,

```
#include <Arduino.h>

//Declared weak in Arduino.h to allow user redefinitions.
int atexit(void (*func)()) { return 0; }

// Weak empty variant initialization function.
// May be redefined by variant files.
void initVariant() __attribute__((weak));
void initVariant() { }

int main(void)
{
    init();

    initVariant();

#if defined(USBCON)
    USBDevice.attach();
#endif

    setup();

    for (;;) {
        loop();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run (i.e. in the same folder)

`cl /EHsc main.cpp /Fetest.exe`

I got this error even though `Arduino.h` in the same folder

`main.cpp(20) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Arduino.h': No such file or directory`

My question is is it possible to run the libraries without using the IDE with `cl` compiler?

Comment: @DavidGrayson, the file in the directory of the .exe. The problem was the angle bracket. Change this `<Arduino.h>` to `"Arduino.h" but it throws another errors `\stdlib.h(114) : error C3646: '__attribute__' : unknown override specifier`. I'm not sure if arduino is compatible with `cl` compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.  Arduino libraries are usually meant to run on an embedded processor like an AVR.  If they access any of the hardware of the processor then you will have a hard time editing those libraries to make them run on Windows under the cl compiler.

Another issue is that the libraries are meant to be compiled with gcc, which has features cl does not have.

However, it would help if you would say what toolkit and what libraries you are using instead of being vague.

Comment: well my plan to use all the libraries of arduino if this possible. I would like to get started at least with simple project like LED blinking. I've seen some ppl use visual studio in Youtube. How about using `MinGW`?

Comment: You are going to need some sort of AVR or Arduino simulation framework to do that, you can't just compile the library using cl.  An LED can generally be turned on with the Arduino functions `pinMode` and `digitalWrite`.  The Arduino IDE comes with implementations of those functions that actually write to AVR hardware registers.  If you want to see a virtual LED on your screen turn on, then you have to get alternate implementations of those functions.  I don't know where you could find a tool like that, but those YouTube videos and their descriptions might help.

Comment: Try asking on the Arduino Stack Exchange site.  Here is a question similar to yours: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/61/can-i-program-for-arduino-without-having-a-real-board

Answer (score 1):

I'm not even sure if Arduino is fully compatible with cl compiler, maybe you prefer to use [Visual Micro](http://www.visualmicro.com/) instead of this to program for Arduino in Visual Studio.